# Why there is additional white space at the bottom of the hr tag?

Tags: html, css

why there is additional white space at the bottom of the hr tag?i wrapped my code with div tag but it has
the white space at the bottom of the hr element.
i want to remove the white space after the hr element.
[image]

```css
{
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #181818;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #3ea6ff;
}

.home {
  font-size: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

#night {
  color: #f34601;
}

#mare {
  color: #3ea6ff;
}

#left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f34601 50%, #3ea6ff 50%);
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home logo">
  <h1 id="mare">
    <span id="night">Night</span> mare
  </h1>
  <hr id="left">
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding a CSS rule of `hr { margin: 0; }`

Comment: `inline-block` elements act like that. Change it to `block` or `flex`.

Comment: but it is not working

Comment: hr{margin:0;} is not working

Comment: remove `display: inline-block` from `#left`

Comment: DJave's suggestion of using margin:0 works for me.

Comment: display:block worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `display:block` instead of `inline-block`.

```css
{
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #181818;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #3ea6ff;
}

.home {
  font-size: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

#night {
  color: #f34601;
}

#mare {
  color: #3ea6ff;
}

#left {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f34601 50%, #3ea6ff 50%);
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home logo">
  <h1 id="mare">
    <span id="night">Night</span> mare
  </h1>
  <hr id="left">
</div>
```

Or try `display:flex`

```css
{
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #181818;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #3ea6ff;
}

.home {
  font-size: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

#night {
  color: #f34601;
}

#mare {
  color: #3ea6ff;
}

#left {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f34601 50%, #3ea6ff 50%);
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home logo">
  <h1 id="mare">
    <span id="night">Night</span> mare
  </h1>
  <hr id="left">
</div>
```

Simply removing `display` will also work as `hr` is a block element by default.

```css
{
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #181818;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #3ea6ff;
}

.home {
  font-size: 3em;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

#night {
  color: #f34601;
}

#mare {
  color: #3ea6ff;
}

#left {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f34601 50%, #3ea6ff 50%);
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home logo">
  <h1 id="mare">
    <span id="night">Night</span> mare
  </h1>
  <hr id="left">
</div>
```